# How to change column name in powerquery without giving the actual column name in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I am trying to change the name of each column but when I do it through VBA I need to type in the actual name of that column and then type the what it should change to. I will give the code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Or ORder", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(""" & ourOrder & """), null, true)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item=""Sheet1"",Kind=""Sheet""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{""Column1"", type any}" & _
        ", {""CROWN"", type any}, {""March 15th, 2021"", type text}, {""Column4"", type any}, {""Column5"", type any}})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Removed Top Rows"" = Table.Skip(#""Changed Type"",2)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Renamed Columns"" = Table.RenameColumns(#""Removed Top Rows"",{{""Column1"", ""QTY""}, {""CROWN"", ""ITEM""}, {""March 15th, 2021"", ""Part""}, {""Column5"", ""Price""}})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filter" & _
        "ed Rows"" = Table.SelectRows(#""Renamed Columns"", each [QTY] <> null and [QTY] <> """")" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filtered Rows"""
```

As you can see in the `#""Renamed Columns""` part I have to give in the actual name right now and then change but the thing is it can change for different excel file. So is there a way that I can change the name of the columns without actually quoting what the current name is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This renames all the columns in powerquery.  You can adapt for VBA

if there are three columns:

```
= Table.RenameColumns( Source, List.Zip( { Table.ColumnNames( Source ), { "New Col 1", "New Col 2", "New Col 3" } } ) )
```